# Should I forget dynamic memory allocation and pointers and always pass by v?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have noticed that most C++ experts always advice it's better to pass by value, due to RVO. This allows me not worry too much about pointer manipulation and is easier to write code as well. No complaints there. This makes me wonder whether it is the correct approach to not use dynamic memory allocation (on the heap) at all and always pass parameters and return results by value?

This means instead of coming up with signatures like this:

```
Character* getCharacter(Sprite *sprite, Action* action)
```

I should more or less stick to signatures like:

```
Character getCharacter(Sprite sprite, Action action)
```

Is my understanding correct? or did I juth think i thaw a putthy cath?

Comment: Passing by const reference is normally the accepted way unless you need a copy (or a normal reference if you need to modify the original). Returning by value is good.

Comment: Passing by value has very little to do with dynamic allocation?!

Comment: Programming requires thinking.  You're not going to get by with a list of "always do this"/"never do that" rules. Sometimes passing and  returning pointers is the correct thing to do, sometimes it's not.

Comment: I would say in C++11 plus the missing `std::make_unique<T>`, there's no need to use `new` and `delete` at all.  But you still have to think about whether you should use a reference, a raw pointer, a `unique_ptr`, a `shared_ptr`, or something else.

Comment: @aschepler, And even then C++14 will break in `std::make_unique` and `std::optional` for more consideration.

Comment: Is it possible to kindly tell when to use pointers? When to allocate on the heap and get a raw pointer and use that? I thought that is efficient. But, in almost all questions I ask, folks almost tell me to  stop allocating on the heap and pass by value. I'm much confused as a C++ noob here.

Comment: @dev_nut, Like aschepler says, if you find an absolute need to use `new`, you'd better clearly know you need it instead of something like a smart pointer or container. Chances are you'll be 110% sure you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They each have there pro's and con's. remember that using words like "always" is an absolute. Only the Dark Side deals in absolutes.

So let's look at each way and when we would use them.

- Pass by value is good when the object being passed is smaller (since a local copy gets made). It is also good if you want to be sure to not accidentally change the original data. Its shortcoming is it makes a local copy and that can be bad if it is really big.
- Pass by reference only passes a memory address. Therefore, large objects can be passed for a relatively low footprint. Also, with a reference, you can modify the original (this is both good and bad). This enables you to "return" more than one variable (so to speak). So obviously, the big con here is that you can mistakenly change the original data.
- Constant pass by reference is generally accepted to be a very strong candidate for doing things. It has the pros of both pass by reference and value. Low footprint since it is a reference AND you can't change the original. There aren't many cons accept for the fact that your use of the variable in the method needs to change a little. Remember, its a const and therefore cannot be modified in the function.

Remember, there is no magic-bullet. Nothing is always better. Determine what you need and select the right tool for the job.

EDIT: also, has been said. Passing is not the same as dynamic allocation. dynamic allocation only happens with the "new" keyword. My suggestion would be to avoid the "new" keyword for now until you have a better understanding of arguments and pointers.

Comment: Thanks for being very descriptive. But, you see whenever I thought I should use pointers (I was using a lot of std::maps with some pointers, cos the object that was using them had to be invoked through many other objects during it's lifecycle) ppl were screaming at me to pass by value, as if I'm crazy to even think of allocating an object on the heap and pass a pointer. They were always talking about RVO (runtime value optimization) and there's no benefit you get from that and blah blah. I thought I was crazy. But, nw I knw what I tht was right. Allocating on the heap and passing ptrs r fine.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you allocate an object on the heap typically is driven by one of the following concerns:

1. If the new object needs to outlive the function that creates it, the object must be allocated on the heap.
2. If the object is very large, and does not fit on the stack, then you must allocate it on the heap.

Beyond that, the choice of pass by value or pass by reference is determined by the semantics. If you want to operate on a copy, pass by value. If you want to operate on the actual object, pass by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is simply utterly untrue. There is some light advice to pass by value instead of the mainstream const-ref in the *special case* where the function will copy the argument to a local variable anyway.

And for passing by-nonconst-pointer, pass by value was never an alternative. The first implies an optional out or inout param and the second and input param.

And mentioned dynamic allocation in question title just fits no way with the content.

Your understanding in definitely not correct.

Comment: Damn it, I just thought I could pick it up and code away like I did with Java with grandma Google's help. Now I got to bury myself in one of those recommended reads. Oh well. Looks like there haz no shortcuts.